# Прыжки в игре на pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, разработка-игр, pygame

Сделал логику прыжка на Pygame, все работает, все плавно, но почему то игрок приземляется не на туже точку по оси y, а чуть выше, и так после каждого прыжка.
Пробовал в конце условия `if self.isJump is True:` написать `self.rect.y = height` (на этой позиции по игрику игрок появляется), но после этого, после прыжка, игрок пропадает с экрана вовсе.

```
import pygame
import random
import os

pygame.init()
width, height = 1280, 720
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('Pygame_template')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

# assets
game_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
imgs_folder = os.path.join(game_folder, 'img')
player_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(imgs_folder, 'hero.png'))
player_left_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(imgs_folder, 'hero_walk_left.png'))
player_right_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(imgs_folder, 'hero_walk_right.png'))


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = player_img
        self.image.set_colorkey(0)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.midbottom = (width / 2, height)
        self.isJump = False
        self.jumpCount = 10

    def update(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        self.image = player_img

        if (keys[pygame.K_LEFT]) and (self.rect.x >= 0):
            self.rect.x -= 5
            self.image = player_left_img
            self.image.set_colorkey(0)

        if (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]) and (self.rect.x <= 1145):
            self.rect.x += 5
            self.image = player_right_img
            self.image.set_colorkey(0)

        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            self.isJump = True

        if self.isJump is True:

            if self.jumpCount >= -10:

                if self.jumpCount < 0:
                    self.rect.y += (self.jumpCount ** 2) / 2
                else:
                    self.rect.y -= (self.jumpCount ** 2) / 2

                self.jumpCount -= 1

            else:
                self.isJump = False
                self.jumpCount = 10


clock = pygame.time.Clock()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)

running = True

while running:
    clock.tick(60)

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

# Обновление
all_sprites.update()

# Рендеринг
screen.fill((156, 113, 58))
all_sprites.draw(screen)
pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: *"self.rect.y = height (на этой позиции по игрику игрок появляется)"* - игрок появляется не на этой позиции. Ну и взлет и падение как-то странно считаются.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это накапливаемая ошибка округления. Потому как в этом месте

```
if self.jumpCount < 0:
    self.rect.y += (self.jumpCount ** 2) / 2
else:
    self.rect.y -= (self.jumpCount ** 2) / 2
```

вы используете обычное деление (т.е. справа у вас получается число типа float), но результат (координата) у вас должен быть целым.

Просто замените в этих формулах обычное деление `/` на целочисленное `//`.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Почему то сам не догадался что из-за нецелочисленного деления координата по y все время сьезжает вверх)